# how to unmap the memory which is mapped using remap_pfn_range()

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm

There are multiple approaches to map kernel memory to user space. 
Some say use `splice()`, `mmap()`, etc.

I am calling `mmap()` with a descriptor of our own pseudo char device file like '/dev/mem'.

When calling `mmap()` with with our own pseudo char device file, internally in mmap registered `file_operation` function pointer, we can invoke `remap_pfn_range()` for mapping memory..

Now that process might have got terminated/killed/clean exit().
How to remove those mappings from kernel space. I am working on ARMv7-A.

Can anyone explain what happens about these memory mappings when the process gets killed/terminated? Does kernel remove the mappings by itself or do we need to `unmap` explicitly?

Comment: Can you please state concisely what you are talking about. Do you want to know about */dev/mem* or how to write your own? *these mapping*, etc are a little vague. You start with `splice()` (which avoids mapping memory) and `mmap()` which are user space calls.  Later you talk about kernel API calls.  Your question is currently not clear.

Comment: The lifetime of a custom driver/device will depend on the use case of that device; so the kernel provides a variety of ways to ensure the mappings are freed.  Is it system global or a per-process mapping or some other lifetime?

Comment: Main requirement is to understand the functionality of remap_pfn_range() .
Suppose it is maintaining some mappings in  kernel space, how can we remove those.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it via `release` when last copy exits.

```
struct file_operations {
  ...
  int (*release) (struct inode *, struct file *);
  ...
}
```

From [LDD](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch03.html)

> This operation is invoked when the file structure is being released.
>   Like open, release can be missing.[ Note that release isn't invoked
>   every time a process calls close. Whenever a file structure is shared
>   (for example, after a fork or a dup), release won't be invoked until
>   all copies are closed. If you need to flush pending data when any copy
>   is closed, you should implement the flush method.

Answer (score 1):

`mmap` maps an external (to the process) memory space to the virtual address space of the process calling it. Memory maybe a shared memory segment, a file... Unlike the physical memory segment it maps to, `mmap` just creates a "link" to that segment, and returns an address that can be seen and used from the calling process.

When the `mmap` calling process terminates (naturally, killed..) the mappings it created are automatically unmapped.

The physical memory region that was mapped, however, and that may be used by other processes (or no), remains available.

[`man mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)

You may close the mapping from the program before it dies,

```
int munmap(void *addr, size_t length);
```

Comment: That's not what OP asking. He has his own device so he needs to implement the parts doing the "automatically".

Comment: @artlessnoise I seriously doubt that "mmap() can be called with descriptor of '/dev/mem' or our own pseudo char device file.
When calling mmap() with with our own pseudo char device file"

Comment: Ah, good point.  I just read */dev/mem*.  He should use like */dev/mem*.

Comment: munmap() does cleanup in process space.
when remap_pfn_range() is called in kernel space, what is functionality it does , other than mapping to user space.
Does it maintain anything in kernel space?

Comment: *remap_pfn_range()* does the actual mapping (driver side) and uses data that is allocated user side (by *mmap()*). Therefore, driver side after the call to *remap_pfn_range()* there is no specific data to be freed, that will be done from user side by an explicit call to *munmap()* or automatically when the user process dies.

Comment: may be right.
not sure if any other page table is maintained in kernel(). If the see the code in kernel, it calls pmd_alloc-> pud_alloc->pte_alloc.....
Does all these allocations freed by munmap().
Theoretically , it should be freed.